# Filter on Count Aggregation

Tags: data-visualization, kibana

I have been looking for the solution on the internet from quite a while and I'm still not sure that if it is possible on Kibana or not.
Suppose I apply filter on term and it gives me count of the respective terms but I want the results to show only those terms where count equals a specific value.
Being more specific,
I want to find out the number of tills which are the most busy (most number of transactions). Currently when I apply a filter on term and count it shows me the all the tills with their respective transaction count. What I want is that to show only those tills where the count is equal to let's say 10.
In other words a similar functionality like HAVING clause in relational dbms.
I have found a lot of work arounds of the same usecase but I'm looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you're asking. I think You can search the field in question with proper parameters. For example, for the field 'field_name' with more than 10 hits, try following Lucene query:

```
field_name:(*) AND count:[10 TO *]
```

For the exact result of field_name with count=10, query:

```
field_name:(*) AND count:[10]
```

Let me know if this was what you were looking for!